# How to upgrade SQLite to the latest version on Synology DSM?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, synology

Problem: How to upgrade SQLite to the latest version on Synology DSM?

Environment: Server is a Synology NAS Model DS216+, DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4. Client is a Win 10 PC running SSH to access to server via command prompt.

Have tried:

1. Installed ipkg and used it to install sqlite version 3.8.1-3.
2. Then used pip3 to install django version 3.0.5.
3. Following the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/
4. After typed this command: "$ python manage.py runserver" got the following: "  File "/opt/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 65, in check_sqlite_version raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.8.1)."
5. Checked on SQLite.org web site and the latest version is Version 3.31.1 (2020-01-27).
6. Searched Synology support site, and other web resources and could not find info on how to upgrade the SQLite (3.8.1-3) to the latest version (3.31.1).